# When changing SQLite data in external editor file is not copied to the device

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

My iOS app uses object screen coordinates stored in SQLite file. During development I'm changing coordinates for some objects. To get this reflected on the device I always have to delete app from device. Only then SQLite with changed data is copied over to the device after compilation. No code is changed, only SQLite contents.

1. Is there a way to copy only SQLite file to the app on the iPad (without recompile and app deletion)
2. Is there a way to tell Xcode to always copy and overwrite SQLite file after compile and deployment?

Janis

Comment: I dealt with this years ago.  I seem to remember that a clean followed by a recompile did the trick.  I'm not aware of a way to force Xcode to always overwrite the SQLite file, though I'd love to find out I'm wrong.